# .sln file lost, then how to run a project which has a database connection?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a project of Online Book Shop like Flipkart but now I lost my .sln file of this project, it has a database connection so how can I create a new .sln file and run my project??

I tried to make blank .sln file and want to add all files of my project but failed to do that so anyone has a solution share.....

Comment: Failed with what error? Adding all projects to new solution should work.

Comment: it is not working.... when i click to add existing project a new window is opening then i m going to add my project folder but when selecting the folder showing blank...

Comment: Make an update out of your version control system (SVN, Git, TFS, etc.).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to file-> New Project in Visual Studio.  Then go to "Other Project Types"-> "Visual Studio Solutions".  You should see "Blank Solution".  Just create a blank solution.  Once you have that right click on the solution and go to "Add"->"Existing Project" and select your projects.

Comment: it is not working.... when i click to add existing project a new window is opening then i m going to add my project folder but when selecting the folder showing blank...

Comment: You must have a website then not a web application project.  Instead of clicking on "Existing Project" select "Existing Website" and just select the folder your web files are in.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions contains projects. So you have to add projects to a blank solution.

So, first create a new blank solution. Then right click on the solution icon and select Add existing project. Then browse to the project folder and select the .*proj file.

Finally check if any external reference is missing, and add it to the project references.
At this point you should be able to build the solution.